# Do we need to authenticate for Internal Microservice?

Tags: jwt, microservices, single-page-application, identityserver4, identity

I have a spa app and three APIs (A, B, C)

A, B are **public microservices** and C is **internal microservice**.

[image]

Which way is best for that?

## 1. First way

```
SpaClient 
Scope = A, B, C
```

Spa App gets a token of SpaClient from Identity Provider.

Call A api, B api from Spa App using token, and A api calls C api using same token.

## 2. Second way

```
SpaClient 
Scope = A, B

CClient
Scope = C
```

Spa App gets a token of SpaClient from Identity Provider.

Call A api, B api, and A api calls additional to Identity Provider to fetch a token of CClient and call C Api using token of CClient.

This case, Identity Provider needs to generate new token on every request in order to call C Api from A Api.

## 3. Third way

```
SpaClient 
Scope = A, B
```

Spa App gets a token of SpaClient from Identity Provider.

Call A api, B api from Spa App using token, and A api calls C api without token (no authentication in C Api).

## Do we need to authenticate for Internal Microservice ?

Comment: If the api is internal and doesn't required any authentication or authorization then you can avoid extra step of authentication which is over head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C Api` is a resource which needs to be protected. You can do this on a global level, which may all be fine. But what I think can be a problem is *how to access the resource in the flow*?

If the resource has user depended information then how are you going to pass this information? `A Api` can send any `sub`, claiming it is *on behalf* of this user. There is no way `C Api` can tell. And how do you prevent `B Api` from accessing the resource?

For maintainability and security reasons I would implement the same security on all api's. And in this case the problem can be solved by using [delegation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant).

That way no other resources or clients can access `C Api`. The resource knows which client made the call and knows for sure it is on behalf of the user they say, as this is part of the access token and can be verified (introspection) by IdentityServer.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication should be implemented for all services, regardless of whether it is expose to the user or not.

If the service is acting on behalf of a user as in a synchronous request from UI touching both A and C in your example, use Authorization Code flow of OAuth2, where same token would flow through A to C.

If the service is NOT acting on behalf of the user as in a batch job or the consumer of a streaming platform, use Client flow of OAuth2 where C (in your example) would acquire its own token from authorization server.

Leaving a microservice open without requiring any authentication from client is not secured regardless of how it is used and where it is positioned in the call flow.